# How to use iOS SDK 4.2 with Xcode 4.0.2

Tags: xcode4, ios-4.2

I installed Xcode4.0.2 yesterday and attempted to build and run a project developed by someone else, who was using an older version of Xcode (3.2.5) and iOS 4.2.

By default it seems, Xcode sets the project's "Base SDK" to 'Latest iOS (iOS 4.3)'. When I try to change that, my only iOS SDK options are "iOS 4.3" or "Latest iOS (iOS 4.3)". On my machine (Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs) I have "iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk", as well as one for 3.2, 4.0 and 4.1.

In the Base SDK dialog, I tried choosing "Other..." to set the SDK to something other than the 4.3 options listed. Instead of getting a list of additional installed SDKs I get a text area where I need to manually enter an SDK. I tried "iOS 4.2" but I don't believe that worked.

Why isn't the list of available SDKs being populated with all the ones on my machine, and how can I set the SDK to 4.2?

Thanks!

Mat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to select latest SDK, and then if you want the product to work on an earlier version you will want to select iOS Deployment Target, you can go all the way back to 3.0.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for!